# problem with resizing border

Tags: c#, wpf

There is user control(button) inside the border.When mouse leave the borderborder is    getting minimization slowly slowly and button.Then content of button is lost alphabet wise.

For example:
General Informatio, General Informati, General Informat,
General Informa, General Inform, General Infor,
General Info, General Inf, General In, 
General I,General and so on..
But I would like to show the content like tihs

General
Information
and then lost.

```
<UserControl x:Class="HID_okworkbench.readerButton"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:HID_okworkbench="clr-namespace:HID_okworkbench"
x:Name="readerButtonControl" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="11"
Height="auto" Width="auto">
<Grid>
    <Button Name="omniButton" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                                Style="{DynamicResource MyBottomLeftButtonStyle}" 
                                Background="White" 
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="0">
        <DockPanel Name="dockPanelOmni" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Image Name="omniButtonImage" DockPanel.Dock="Left"  Height="35" Width="35" 
                                       Stretch="Uniform" />
            <Label Name="omniButtonLabel" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Foreground="DarkBlue" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            </Label>
        </DockPanel>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why not give the button a fixed Width?

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you're saying, but try adding Width="Auto" to everything, including the control that will be hosting the instance of your readerButtonControl in question.

If this doesn't help add some screenshots and the xaml containing the instance of your readerButtonControl.